# Can't see connected devices ip with "iw dev wlan0 station dump" on raspberry

Tags: networking, raspbian, arp

I have successfully turned my Raspberry Pi into a WiFi access point, but I'm having trouble getting notifications when a new device connects or disconnects from it. Specifically, I would like to receive the IP address of any newly connected devices.

Currently, I am using the `sudo arp` command every n seconds to check for new devices. This method works well for detecting new connections, but there is a delay when a device disconnects. I've noticed that the `HWaddress` field in the ARP table becomes `(incompatible)` before the table is updated to reflect that the device has disconnected.

I have found that using the

```
iw dev wlan0 station dump
```

command provides up-to-date information on connected devices, but it only shows the MAC address and not the assigned IP address, which I need to obtain.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to reliably get notified when a device connects or disconnects from my access point and receive its IP address.

Comment: If you are using hostapd, check out [this question from superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1071354/hostapd-execute-a-command-when-there-is-new-connection-established).

Comment: wlan works at its layer. On top if this there's the remaining parts of the network stack (ARP, IP, DHCP with these etc...). `iw` is a specialized tool, it doesn't know anything about an IP address (nor would hostapd, but yes having it help trigger scripts which would figure this out is a good idea).

Comment: `arpwatch` (it's Open Source, use any search engine), or `ip monitor ...` (`man ip ip-monitor`) are tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two commands...

iw dev wlan0 station dump to get a list of valid MAC addresses, then use the arp command to get the mapping between IP and MAC addresses.

Only log the ones that match the list from the station dump.

This could easily be done in PERL with hashes (create a hash of MAC->IP from the arp command, then go through the list of MAC addresses retrieved from the iw command and pull out the corresponding IP from the hash).